# mysql compare two tables to find matched records

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all data from `tbl_attn_temp` which `TraineeID` are match with `tbl_assigned` `TraineeID` or `tbl_instructor_info` `InstructorID`. But I get all the data match with `tbl_assigned` `TraineeID`. `tbl_instructor_info` data not or showing with this query as below:

tbl_attn_temp

[image]

tbl_assigned

[image]

tbl_instructor_info

[image]

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl_attn_temp t1, tbl_instructor_info t2, tbl_assigned t3
WHERE t1.TraineeID=t3.TraineeID or t2.InstructorID
GROUP by t1.traineeid, t1.attnDate
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `OR` condition is wrong. it should be like this ***WHERE (t1.TraineeID = t3.TraineeID OR t1.TraineeID = t2.InstructorID)***
Query should be like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tbl_attn_temp t1, tbl_instructor_info t2, tbl_assigned t3
WHERE (t1.TraineeID = t3.TraineeID OR t1.TraineeID = t2.InstructorID)
GROUP by t1.traineeid, t1.attnDate
```

Comment: The query seems to be right: you could  tought mention why the original query does not work (not my downvote ;))

Comment: @Mikey Ok.. thanks.. let me explain it to this answer :)

Comment: @MirAbzalAli Welcome.. if it worked then please accept. i have explained why your query didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT t1.traineeid, t1.attnDate
FROM tbl_attn_temp t1, tbl_instructor_info t2, tbl_assigned t3
WHERE (t1.TraineeID=t3.TraineeID or t1.TraineeID=t2.InstructorID)
GROUP by t1.traineeid, t1.attnDate
```

If you Use GROUP BY clause,you can allow to select group by columns (traineeid,attnDate in your case)  and will allow aggregate functions to be performed on the one or more columns.

Comment: It is not true for MySQL: you may select all the columns - you just get one of the values present in the group

Comment: let me check in MYSQL

Comment: @Mikey,Yeah you are correct,we may select all the columns in MYSQL,but in other DBs it wont work.